# Casting Leveled Action Spell and Bonus Action Scroll in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, actions

I'd like to cast Spirit Guardians and Sanctuary (Bonus) in the same turn, but I can't.  So I bought some Sanctuary scrolls.  Can I cast Spirit Guardians and read a Sanctuary (Bonus) Scroll in the same turn?

If I replace the Scroll with any Magic Item that allows a spell effect to be cast as a Bonus action, would it change the answer?

Answer (score 6):

### No, scrolls count as casting.

[Using a scroll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5418-spell-scroll):

> [...] If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and **cast its spell** without providing any material components. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible. **Casting the spell by reading the scroll requires the spell’s normal casting time. Once the spell is cast,** the words on the scroll fade, and it crumbles to dust. [...]

[Bonus action spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting):

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

As using a scroll counts as casting a spell and the rules for bonus action spells have no exception for spells powered by a scroll or other magic item (note that some magic items, such as potions, say "you gain the effect" rather than counting as you casting a spell), it has the same restrictions.